# How to change inquiry form from left to right and disable auto open pop-up option

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, contact-form

I have tried a lot to change the position of my inquiry form from left to right. I tried changing float into right and many more, but nothing worked. As I'm not technically sound, just looking out for the help. Can anyone suggest me how to do this?  By the way, we are using Contact form  7 plugin. Our developer made some changes to the code to make it float and auto open. The CSS of the form is:

```
.collapse
{
    z-index: 9999;
    position: fixed;
    top:14%;
    min-height:450px;
    overflow-y: hidden;

}
.collapsibleform
{
    max-width:300px;
    background: #fff;
    left:-300px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding: 5%;

}
.collapsibleform input[type=text],.collapsibleform input[type=email],.collapsibleform input[type=tel],.collapsibleform textarea{
    background: #e5e5e5 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.collapsibleform input[type=text]:focus,.collapsibleform input[type=email]:focus,.collapsibleform input[type=tel]:focus,.collapsibleform textarea:focus{
    color:#333;
}
.collapsibleform input[type=submit]
{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    background: #540e71 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 2px solid #540e71;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    height: 27px;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 141px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.collapsibleform textarea
{
    height:70px;
}
.collapsibleform input[type=submit]:hover
{
    background: none;
    color: #540e71;
}
.collapse a
{

    display: none;
    float: left;
    background: url(images/violetbtn.jpg) no-repeat;
    width: 40px;
    height: 146px;
    color:transparent;
    overflow:hidden;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
    top:180px;

}
.collapsibleform .captcha-334
{
    float: left;
    width: auto;
}
.formget_box
{
    display: none !important;
    left: -275px !important;
}

.collapsibleform h3
{
   margin-bottom: 16px;
   font-size: 24px;
   color: #000;
   padding-bottom: 7px;
   border-bottom: 1px dotted #e1e1e1; 
}
.wpcf7-form-control-wrap.captcha-334 {
    float: right;
    width: 68%;
}
img.wpcf7-captcha-captcha-334 {
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    margin-top:7px;
}
.collapsibleform h5.heading
{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin:5px 0;
}
ul.search_results
{
    z-index: 999!important;
}
.collapse div.wpcf7-validation-errors
{
    display: none!important;
}
```

Comment: Try add your code to https://jsfiddle.net/ it will help us to solve the problem

Comment: I'm not sure what is jsfiddle.net but I tried to place the code in CSS Section. https://jsfiddle.net/g4Lkzxjk/2/ . Am I right? I'm not a Developer but just want to do this my own.

Comment: Yes , now add example html to html section

Comment: I gave form html code ?!

Comment: In your question is not part of the html

Comment: I will explain you. Actually we are using contact form 7 for contact forms. As we thought of giving floating left side inquiry form, Our developer made some correction in style sheets (the code i placed in CSS Section). And gave the short code in header.php. Now I need the form from left to Right and also want to disable the auto open option. You can see the live form I'm talking about in this website http://www.iqonlinetraining.com/   (left inquiry form) . Hope u understand.

Comment: if u want to put left form to right just add to .collapse attribute rigth: 0px. When it comes to auto open the option you mean the central form?

Comment: Tried it. Its not working :(

Comment: No, once after the page loads the left inquiry auto opens..

Comment: To pop up does not open automatically try to comment out the code $ ( '. main-link-pop-up'). delay (15000) .queue (function () {
   $ (This) .trigger ( 'click');
  });

Comment: where should I give this. I tried it but not working. I gave it in CSS

Comment: Comment it in main.js. To change .collapse add this to your css main file : .collapse {right: 0px !important;}

Comment: Really I appreciate your help!  I did whatever u said its not working :(

Comment: On your page file main.js I do not see that commented out the line which I had requested and where you added the code associated with css? Ok I see .collapse styles are in style.css but here I too dont see my requested value for .collapse

Comment: I have inserted it in CSS. And im not sure about js file. We are using wordpress

Comment: Ok so try to change this: setTimeout(function() {
        $(".collapsibleform").animate({
         left:'0',
         width:'300px',

        });
        $(".collapse a").fadeIn();
    }, 5000); to setTimeout(function() {
        $(".collapsibleform").animate({
         right:'0px',
         width:'300px',

        });
        $(".collapse a").fadeIn();
    }, 5000); of course in main.js file